# preprocess function call - $vars[node_title] does not work as a parameter, while $vars['node-title'] does

Tags: theming

I am writing a preprocess function. I provided a linkIt function that does the linking for me:

```
function linkIt($what, $where) {


return '<a href="' . $where . '" class="' . $what . '.-preprocess-field preprocess-field">' . t($what) . '</a>';
```

}
If I call it this way:

```
$test= linkIt('XXX', $vars[node_url]);
```

it produces a Drupal error 'Use of undefined constant node_url - assumed 'node_url''. If I call it

```
$test= linkIt('XXX', $vars['node_url']);
```

with quotes around `node_url`it works fine.
The former syntax is properly evaluated if I do not pass it as a function paramter, for example in

```
$vars['opis'] = '<a href="' . $vars[node_url] . '" class="opis-preprocess-field">' . t('XXX') . '</a>'
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts:

This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the quotes). PHP may in the future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

See [PHP:Arrays - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) Chapter "Array do's and don'ts"